# access method when passing dictionary array to another method

Tags: swift, dictionary, parameters, parameter-passing, accessor

In my swift code below I want to create a access method that transfers over a dictionary item which in this case the dictionary is called girlsname. The item should be transferred from the view did load func to the func called submit. I dont know if I set up the submite parameter list correct right now its causing a compile error.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var girlsName = ["a": "Jessica Biel", "b": "Gwen Stefani","c":"Jessica Alba" ]
    
    var btn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        [btn].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                green: .random(in: 0.9...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.7...1),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
        }
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submite(randomVal:)), for: .touchDown)
        let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(girlsName.count)))
        let randomVal = Array(girlsName.values)[index]
        
        submite(randomVal:randomVal)
    }
    

    @objc func submite(randomVal: String) {
        
        print(String())
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's this?  print(String())

Comment: you don't need to do that for random value just take random value like `girlsName.randomelemnet()`. and can you tell me what's the error you got??

Comment: Problem with arc4random method - Take a look : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115690?answerId=357251022#357251022

Comment: @ElTomato If I just put print string this error comes up Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Comment: @jatinfl that looks like it works but I still need to pass it from method a to method b

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to pass parameters into @objc func. You can use like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var randomVal: String = ""
    // ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         // ...
                
         btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submite), for: .touchDown)
         let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(girlsName.count)))
         randomVal = Array(girlsName.values)[index]
      }
            
      @objc func submit() {
          print(randomVal)
      }
}
```

Comment: this does not produce a random name its the same name each time

Comment: It's easy. You just need to move the code generate randomVal to the submit function